# How to use Spring method DELETE

Tags: spring, rest, http-delete

I have some customers in ArrayList and when I want through Postman delete (with id) it is not working : 500 - Internal Error. Please Could someone help me ?

> Delete customer
> DELETE http://localhost:8080/api/customers/{customerId}

```
@DeleteMapping("/api/customers{customerId}")
public void deleteCustomer(@PathVariable  Long customerId) {
    customers.remove(this.customers.get(Math.toIntExact(customerId)));

}
```

Comment: The answers thus far suggest that the culprit is your path (missing the slash after customers).  This is definitely an issue, but this would not cause a 500, internal server error.  Share the contents of the error, only then can this question be answered...and yes, you will have to fix that path too.

Answer (score 1):

**try like this** you did not add **"/"** in delete mapping.

```
@DeleteMapping("/api/customers/{customerId}")
public void deleteCustomer(@PathVariable  Long customerId) {
    customers.remove(this.customers.get(Math.toIntExact(customerId)));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this how you send the request?

```
http://localhost:8080/api/customers/{customerId}
```

If you are sending like this, it won't work because you gave path like this:

```
/api/customers{customerId}
```

In my opinion, either change the path like this:

```
/api/customers/{customerId}
```

Or send the request like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/customers{customerId}
```